# Help with punctuation in non-restrictive clauses

Tags: punctuation, commas, relative-pronouns

Would someone be kind enough to tell me whether the sentence below is OK, considering that 'fashioned' is a past tense verb, 'believe' is a present tense verb, and refuse' is also a present tense verb.

> The people **who** initially fashioned and those **who** now believe **that** the theory and its predictions are well grounded refuse to accept . . . ."

Putting a comma after 'that' seems to separate the subject from its direct object, and rewriting the sentence in the following way made it too wordy:

> The people who initially fashioned the theory and its predictions, and the people who now believe that both are well grounded, refuse to accept . . . ."

Thanks very much.

Comment: The parallelism in the original is indeed somewhat wobbly. Regarding your revision: one doesn't normally *fashion* predictions.

Comment: Thanx. If the "wobbly parallelism" can be overlooked, would changing 'fashioned' to 'formulated' render the sentence acceptable, considering that scientists occasionally formulate predictions, (e.g., here http://bit.ly/2I14stF )

Comment: It’s the theory that’s fashioned; the predictions come along for the ride. So if you don’t mind the wobbly parallelism, the original is fine as is.